# How to parse xml file for cocos2D

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am trying to parse a xml document in my resource folder in my project. The project is a cocos2D project and i am trying to create some type of method to parse the xml file to load levels for my game.

What would be the best way to parse the document? And an example would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any Objective-c XML parser in cocos2d
I suggest you to use [TBXML](http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html)
But instead of having data in your `xml`, you should save it into `plist` and use it directly.

Comment: The thing is i am using a level editor that puts out xml files for the levels. Is there a xml parser already availible in cocos2D? I read about NSXmlParser but im not sure how to use it with a document in my project.

Comment: NSXMLPraser is in coca-touch frame work. I have suggested you a parser which is easy and has example of loading file from your project

Comment: Yes, it seems like what i need. But how do i integrate it with my current project?

Answer (score 0):

If 
1) the speed of parsing and 
2) the convenience of retrieving the data from xml file is important 
3) you do not mind C++ interface
 then the best parser for you is open source:
http://code.google.com/p/pugixml/

**pugixml** is a light-weight C++ XML processing library. It features:
    •   DOM-like interface with rich traversal/modification capabilities
    •   Extremely fast non-validating XML parser which constructs the DOM tree from an XML file/buffer
    •   **XPath 1.0 implementation for complex data-driven tree queries**
    •   Full Unicode support with Unicode interface variants and automatic encoding conversions
The library is extremely portable and **easy to integrate and use**.

I have tested both speed and memory usage against other parsers and use it for last 5 years. 
Documentation is here: http://pugixml.googlecode.com/svn/tags/latest/docs/quickstart.html

Answer (score 0):

Even the post is old, I write the solution here to help other people like me in future. Solution is simple:
- Step 1: Read file content by using FileUtils
- Step 2: Parse file content to tinyxml2 (supported
I have tried and success on loading and reading XML file in cocos2d 3.8

```
#include "tinyxml2/tinyxml2.h"

auto s = FileUtils::getInstance()->getStringFromFile("data.xml");
tinyxml2::XMLDocument *pDoc = new tinyxml2::XMLDocument();
tinyxml2::XMLError errorId = pDoc->Parse(s.c_str(), s.size());
if (errorId == 0) {
     // Write your code here
}
```

data.xml is placed in Resource folder.

Please read http://www.cocos2d-x.org/docs/manual/framework/native/v3/xml-parse/zhparse/zh to know how to iterate tinyxml2 XMLDocument.
Note that you can not use the tutorial in this link to load from file. It always return ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.